# Auth0 Facebook Graph cant get email

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, xamarin, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have the following code that supposedly gets the users "email". "fistname", "lastname", "id" and "gender":

```
var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=first_name,last_name,gender,email"), null, eventArgs.Account);
var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
var obj = JObject.Parse(response.GetResponseText());

var id = obj["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
var firstname = obj["first_name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
var lastName = obj["last_name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
var gender = obj["gender"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
var email = obj["email"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
```

I am able to get every thing properly except the email field, which is null. Am i treating the string wrongly, or is my Uri incorrect to begin with ?

Comment: The more important question is - did the user grant the appropriate permission to your app?

Comment: Uhh, no i did not. I think that i should look into that first then. Any proper way to do that. Would appreciate it if you could guide me.

Comment: Don't forget: A user may have no email although the permission to read was granted, because she registered at Facebook with the mobile number.

Comment: That's a great point, never taught of that. The way i am building my app is storing username and email foreach user (along with other details). This is for the traditional login. And if they choose facebook login, i just set the password to the user facebook id and the email to what i retreive. I now regret my choice. Should come up with a better plan.